# compile_files gives errror for given path of the contract

Tags: solidity, solc, python, django

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

import "./Owned.sol";

contract Greeter is Owned {
    bytes32 public greeting;

    event GreetingChange (
        address indexed changer,
        bytes32 indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _to
    );

    constructor() public {
        greeting = 'Hello';
    }

    function setGreeting(bytes32 _greeting) public onlyBy (owner) {
        emit GreetingChange(msg.sender, greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() view public returns (bytes32) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

here i am importing a contract and when i compile it using py-solc-x compile_files , it gives me error.

```
greeter_interface.compile_source_files()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\blockchain\bpoc\smartContract\interface.py", line 25, in compile_source_files
    self.all_compiled_contracts = compile_files(deployment_list)
  File "D:\blockchain\venv\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 137, in compile_files
    contracts = _parse_compiler_output(stdoutdata)
  File "D:\blockchain\venv\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 73, in _parse_compiler_output
    data['ast'] = sources[source.split(':')[0]]['AST']
KeyError: 'D'
```

Owned.sol 's  file apth is  `'D:\\blockchain\\bpoc\\static\\contracts\\Owened.sol'`

how can i solve this?

Comment: Is the file name really `Owened`? Is the contract name in this file really `Owned`? What is the path of the file which you are trying to compile (the one posted here I suppose)?

Comment: @goodvibration actually mistakenly i have written it  wened, but actually its Owned in my code.. but still giving me the above error.

Comment: @goodvibration path of above file which i am trying to compile is `D:\\blockchain\\bpoc\\static\\contracts\\Greeter.sol`